# Accessing data and displaying in a dropdown

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I have data as :

```
Rooms.
Rooms   : {"_id":{"$oid":"46746766474664"},"RoomID":{"$numberInt":"1"},"RoomDesc":"1st Floor"}
```

I am trying to access and show them in a dropdown.

while mount I am doing this operation.

```
mongodb.db("TestDB")
            .collection("Rooms")
            .find({}, { limit: 1000 })
            .asArray()
            .then(rooms => {
                this.setState({ rooms });
            });
```

and in searable dropdown,

```
   <Dropdown
                                placeholder='Select Rooms'
                                fluid
                                search
                                selection
                                options={this.state.rooms.RoomID}
                                //value={RoomID}
                            />
```

Its always returning Null no entries.
How can I access this data ? should I use Map (or) any other suggestion.
Is there a way we can build on console.

From mongodb prompt all results looks Good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using `Dropdown - Semantic UI React`.you are getting a dropdown with no values because of the structure of your state. Dropdown `options` should be  like this

```
 {
    key: "....",
    text: "...",
    value: "..."
  }
```

using map function to transform you row data to met Dropdown minimum requirements.
**Update**
if MongoDB return a result

```
 rooms: [
        {
          _id: { $oid: "46746766474664" },
          RoomID: { $numberInt: "1" },
          RoomDesc: "1st Floor"
        },
        {
          _id: { $oid: "46746766474665" },
          RoomID: { $numberInt: "2" },
          RoomDesc: "2st Floor"
        }
      ]
```

then you can transform to desirable structure

```
  this.setState({
          options: [
            ...this.state.rooms.map(item => {
              return {
                key: item._id.$oid,
                text: item.RoomDesc,
                value: item.RoomID.$numberInt
              };
            })
          ]
        });
```

Working temporary [Codesandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-fo5oy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)  with a dummy data.

Comment: Thanks Alex. This is working for me.I am able to see the dropdown. but what ever I select its showing still blank. I just  have the same code as yours. not getting what is missing because it is not selecting anything. but I can see dropdown with values. I am having issue to select a Room and get it assigned to a variable so that when submited it goes out. other things I am using onsubmit() not sure what to use here

Comment: make soure you have `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css" />
` in your index.html

Comment: you should use `onChange` for assigning to a variable, I've updated  Codesandbox sample with onChange event, check it out!

Comment: Thanks Alex. I will try and keep this posted. I accepted the answer as it is helping in seeing the dropdown,

Answer (score 0):

If `rooms` is array then you can't just use `this.state.rooms.RoomID`. Probably some loop or map needed

Comment: I tried could not get that working ,can you help me tha map (or) loop?

Comment: ```options={this.state.rooms.map(r => r.RoomID)}``` or ```options={this.state.rooms.map(r => r.RoomID.$numberInt)}```

Comment: r => r.RoomID.$numberInt) when I tried this option I get error undefined. when I try r.RoomID I get a dropdown with no values..its not reading values...not getting what I am missing. data is there in DB

Comment: Basically it is displaying empty rows in dropdown. the number of row are equal to the number of row in DB. some how its not displaying ...

Comment: Can you console.log(this.state.rooms) ?

Comment: console does not print anything. its empty ..but dropdown is having the same number of rows in database.

Comment: Did you use console.log in "then" before "setState"? I want to see rooms array which comes from db

Comment: I did immeditely after setstate. but prints noting.

Comment: Ok so maybe try options={this.state.rooms} we will see structure of each element

Comment: same response there dropdown is empty but with number of elements same as number of rows in database. It is not printing anything

Comment: Maybe there is problem with asArray ? Hard to help because do not know how looks this object retrieved from db

Comment: I am using mongodb. and its SDK in reactjs to query. not getting what could be the issue.....online search says asarray should work ..did not get what could be the issue

Comment: What if you change asArray with toArray ?

Comment: same no change . its not displaying anything even wuth toArray

Comment: Try to run your query in mongo shell

Comment: yes I am able to connect to the database from mongoshell and view the data. I can see all fields